# Laravel implicit binding with pivot relation on user

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I don't think this is possible in Laravel, but I am still going to ask it ;)

I have a `Group` model that has a pivot relation(via `group_user`) to `User`. I have a group controller where this is the index method:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    return $request->user()->groups;
}
```

`groups` in `User` is a `belongsToMany` relation. It will load all groups that have a relation to a user. This will also load the pivot table in the pivot relation.

But now I want to get a single group, this is the controller to get a group with pivot relation:

```
public function show($id, Request $request)
{
    $group = $request->user()->groups()->findOrFail($id);
    $this->authorize('view', $group); // Authorization....

    return $group;
}
```

But I would like to use Implicit binding like this:

```
public function show(Group $group)
{
    $this->authorize('view', $group);

    return $group;
}
```

But it won't load the pivot table because I don't get it via the user...
So I should get the group via the user. But how can I do this with implicit binding?

When this isn't possible: How can I load a pivot relation when I already have the group model?

```
public function show(Group $group, Request $request)
{
    // Load the pivot relation here in $group by using the user in $request->user()? 
    $this->authorize('view', $group);

    return $group;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to eager load the relationship while using implicit binding? If that's the case, I think you could [customize the resolution logic](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-model-binding) and use `with()` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Put this is the `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
Route::bind('group', function ($value) {
    if (auth()->check()) {
        return auth()->user()->groups()->findOrFail($value);
    } else {
        abort(404);
    }
});
```

The `view` policy isn't even needed this way because the group is from the groups relation:

```
public function show(Group $group)
{
    return $group;
}
```